# How to take derivative with respect to a function that is a linear function the variables in the original function?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

\begin{align*}
&\text{Suppose I have a function $f(\vec{x})$, and}
    \,\, x = \begin{bmatrix}
            x_1 \\
            x_2
        \end{bmatrix}\\
&\text{so the derivatives are:}\\
    &\frac{df}{dx} = \begin{bmatrix}
            \frac{df_1}{dx_1} & \frac{df_1}{dx_2}\\
            \frac{df_2}{dx_1} & \frac{df_2}{dx_2}
        \end{bmatrix}\\
&\text{Now I have a vector} \,\, U = \begin{bmatrix}
            u_1 \\
            u_2
        \end{bmatrix} \text{, and} \,\, y = u^Tx.\\
&\text{I want to calculate} \,\, \frac{df}{dy}, \text{can I say} \\
&\frac{df}{dy} = \frac{df}{dx}u \,? \\
&\text{If not, what is the proper way to calculate the derivative?}\\
\end{align*}
Thank you very much!

Comment: Perhaps try with an actual function and u to see what happens when you take the derivatives